# Update response.body in scrapy(without reload)

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I use scrapy and selenium for crawl! my site use ajax for pagination! actully , url no change and so response.body also no change! I want to click with selenium (for pagination) and get self.driver.page_source and use it instead response.body!
So i writed this code :

```
 res = scrapy.http.TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source,
                                           encoding='utf-8')
            print(str(res)) //nothing to print!

            for quote in res.css("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grd_Dr_DXMainTable > tr.dxgvDataRow_Office2003Blue"):
                i = i+1
                item = dict()


                item['id'] =  int(quote.css("td.dxgv:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first())
```

And no error !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace body of original response in scrapy by using `response.replace()` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    response = response.replace(body=driver.page_source)
```

Comment: I use it but doesnt work! anything no change from last!

Comment: @user6935676 it does work, have you considered that both response.body and your new body from driver.page_source are identical?

Comment: very tnx! and plz if you can answer my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683617/webdriverwait-not-working-with-scrapy)   :)